# Alignment issue of the names yaswanth

Tags: javascript

This alignment is not proper so we I need this to be in proper even the child and sub child also increase and the naming alignment should be also proper

The child increase this is also not coming correctly

The naming of the child is not coming in the correct format

This need to fix for the alignment of the names

This is alignment issue
the wording is not proper
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7yp3.jpg)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Tree Example</title>
<style>
    .node {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .node circle {
      fill: #fff;
      stroke: red;
      stroke-width: 2px;
    }
    .node text {
      font: 12px sans-serif;
    }
    .link {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #ccc;
      stroke-width: 2px;
    }
    .node image {  
      clip-path: circle(30px at 30px 30px);  
    } 
</style>
</head>
<body>
load the d3.js library -->  
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
<script>
var treeData = [
  {
    "name": "Top Level",
    "parent": "null",
    "imageUrl": "https://th.bing.com/th/id/R.95e45a66c918a53280e796b44add2d66?rik=oVKQ59XBdewj8Q&pid=ImgRaw&r=0",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Level 2: A",
        "parent": "Top Level",
        "imageUrl" : "https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.c3AFVHO47NA-NvN04HrvkwHaJ9?w=1145&h=1540&rs=1&pid=ImgDetMain",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Son of A",
            "parent": "Level 2: A"
          },
          {
            "name": "Daughter of A",
            "parent": "Level 2: A"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Level 2: B",
        "parent": "Top Level",
        "imageUrl" : "https://th.bing.com/th?id=OIP.OA4NI64f0RtS5yCWLE7IWwHaHa&w=250&h=250&c=8&rs=1&qlt=90&o=6&pid=3.1&rm=2",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Son of A",
            "parent": "Level 2: A",
            "imageUrl" : "https://th.bing.com/th/id/R.58f60f6b81ae6d054b6b4910a9771fbf?rik=%2fKjN%2fqPR7wXaUw&pid=ImgRaw&r=0",
          },
          {
            "name": "Daughter of A",
            "parent": "Level 2: A"
          },
          {
            "name": "Daughter of Aa",
            "parent": "Level 2: Aa"
            
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

// ************** Generate the tree diagram  *****************
var margin = {top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 50, left: 120}, 
    width  = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
    height = 500 - margin.top   - margin.bottom;
var i = 0,
    duration = 750,
    root;
var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([width, height]);
var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.x, d.y]; });
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.top + "," + margin.bottom + ")");
root = treeData[0];
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;`your text`
update(root);
d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "500px");
function update(source) {
  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
      links = tree.links(nodes);
  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });
  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });
  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.x0 + "," + source.y0 + ")"; })
      .on("click", click);
  // Append an <image> element inside each <g> element  
  nodeEnter.append("image")  
      .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return d.imageUrl;})  
      .attr("x", -30) // Adjust the positioning of the image within the node  
      .attr("y", -30)  
      .attr("width", 60)  
      .attr("height", 60)
      .attr("clip-path", "url(#circle-clip)");
  nodeEnter.append("circle")
      .attr("r",  1e-6)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });
  nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -60 : 60; })
      .attr("dy", ".90em")
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);



 
      
  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
  nodeUpdate.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 30)
      .style("fill", "none");
  nodeUpdate.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 2);
  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.x + "," + source.y + ")"; })
      .remove();
  nodeExit.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6);
  nodeExit.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);
  // Update the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });
  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      });
  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", diagonal);
  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      })
      .remove();
  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}
// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```